# Binary Serializer - changing location of serializable class with serialized files

Tags: .net, serialization, binary

I have a class that represents search criteria used to build queries against a datastore. This class is serializable, allowing class instances to be saved to disk and reloaded, providing the business-level feature of saving searches to re-use them.

Here's the problem; I recently changed the location of the class that can be serialized. I didn't change the structure of said class, I only moved it from one project (which no longer exists by its original name) to another. In doing so I realized that I just broke the deserialization of files based on the class as it existed in its prior location.

If possible, I need to be able to "convert" these files. Though the files are in binary format, much of the file is readable as plain text, including the now-invalid namespace. However, just changing the text of said file that I can see will corrupt it, so obviously I'm missing something.

Is there a way to either update the file as some sort of batch process, or point the serializer at the new class location, so the files can be deserialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small program having two copies of the serializable class in each namespace. Then you can read the data from the files using the class in the old namespace and for each instance create an instance of the class in the new namespace where you copy all the fields. You can then serialize the new classes back to files.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking I'll have to do as well. I was hoping it wouldn't come to this, but oh well. If I end up going this route I think I'll take Marc's advice and switch to a text-based serialization method like DataContract. As he said, it won't matter where the object is as long as its form (as seen by the serializer) matches the serialized file.

Comment: I ended up doing this, but serializing the files to XML; those files could then be deserialized by the same object in its new location.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using TypeForwardedToAttribute, so that when the system looks in the **old** assembly, it fails to find the type, but it finds the attribute and looks again in the new assembly. See MSDN for usage, but this works with BinaryFormatter fine.

However, I strongly suggest moving to a contract-based serializer, such as protobuf-net. This will not care of you relocate, rename, etc the types or members. BinaryFormatter is ... Prickly.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned, the old library doesn't even exist in the solution anymore, so I can't put a "forwarding address" in the old location. I was hoping there was a way to configure the serializer directly so it would do the forwarding without even looking in the old place. I'm thinking of just converting to XML serialization, so if this changes again I'm more likely to be able to update the files directly with any necessary changes.

Comment: @KeithS to do that you might be able to use a custom Binder, but ... Hard stuff. If you can use the old dll to deserialize it would be easier.